# Update config file during runtime

Tags: c#

This is a piece of my code:

```
 private void ProcessFile(object filename)
        {
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            ApplicationSettings.ReadSettings();
```

Method ReadSettings() read `key` from .config File. Work of this method finished. Ok, then I've updated `.config` file and want to get new values in next using of this method. How can I do it? The main problem - I got old values from `appSettings` section.

### UPDATE

```
public static int IncreaseSpeedValue { get; private set; }
public static int SilenceDuration { get; private set; }
public static double IncreaseVolume { get; private set; }
public static int VoiceFilter { get; private set; }
public static int SmoothValue { get; private set; }          
public static void ReadSettings()
{
    int tempSettingValue = 0;
    double tempSettingVolume = 0;
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncreaseSpeedValue"], out tempSettingValue);
    IncreaseSpeedValue = tempSettingValue;
    tempSettingValue = 0;
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SilenceDuration"], out tempSettingValue);
    SilenceDuration = tempSettingValue;
    tempSettingValue = 0;
    double.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IncreaseVolume"], out tempSettingVolume);
    IncreaseVolume = tempSettingVolume;
    tempSettingVolume = 0;
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VoiceFilter"], out tempSettingValue);
    VoiceFilter = tempSettingValue;
    tempSettingValue = 0;
    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmoothValue"], out tempSettingValue);
    SmoothValue = tempSettingValue;
    tempSettingValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe "**A**ppSettings"?

Comment: </appSettings>  in my config file

Comment: can we see the code for  `ApplicationSettings.ReadSettings();`?

Comment: and how do you update `.config` file?

Comment: dotctor: just set new values (not code)

Comment: are you using external editor? which file do you modify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80068/discussion-between-dotctor-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall it correctly, there's an issue with  ApplicationSettings refresh when you debugging your code in VS. Try launching .exe directly or switch to Release mode and check if the problem persists.